# PHP parse date/time from title tooltip and format to Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: php, date, parsing, format, tooltip

A "section" tag with "title" attribute contains tooltip text showing last update date and time when mouse pointed over it. Date/time change automatically.

```
<section title="Last updated: Sep 13 2019 11:00 AM>
```

What I need is to output this date in Y-m-d H:i:s format. So far, I found the way to extract whole string. But I have no idea how to change format. My question is, where to look to find that script, that generates this update and inserts it into string, so that it appears like in the example above? Or is it possible to format it with Jquery methods? If yes, then how?

Comment: At least can anyone tell me how to check if that string contains date? I used explode, however it couldn't split the string into elements.

Comment: Found it here on this site: